# Ngixn rewrite and reverse proxy to docker container

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am running 3 services using docker compose on 3 ports: svc1:8081, svc2:8082, and svc3:8083 respectively. I have nginx installed on my host machine (not as a docker container), I want to reverse proxy all the requests to appropriate services so I am rewriting the url inside the nginx location block and performing a reverse proxy.

I am unable to get the results as something the files are not loading (mainly the static file to docker container)

My nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    - ;

   location /svc1/ {
        rewrite ^/svc1(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        
    }

    location /svc2/ {
        rewrite ^/svc2(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        
    }

    location /svc3/ {
        rewrite ^/svc3(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8083;
        
    }
}
```

I would be thankful if anyone can point if I am doing any wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it work when you put NGINX inside your compose stack?

Comment: I did not try that, but will do. But again, does this apply it will not work if nginx is not a part of the service stack?

Comment: It should work but that depends on docker networking and not on nginx. So I assume you checked that the services are reachable from localhost?! Which URI are you calling? Because if you regex `/svc1/` `/svc1` will be not catched. And `server_name` for catching all should be `_` not `-`.

Comment: @araisch I did check it from my host machine and I am able to get the responses from all the 3 services from the localhost endpoints listed. Also let me know if I am rewriting the url correcty as I just want to remove the /sv1 from url and keep the entire url same.

Example: www.localhost/svc1/abc -> www.localhost/abc.

Lastly, I am using docker network and all services are in the same network.

Comment: For this it should work without rewrite by just adding a trailing slash e.g. `location /svc3/` and `proxy_pass http://localhost:8083/;` If it does not work maybe your services have any special need in header or something. Are there any helpful logs from nginx maybe?

Comment: @araisch A log record is this: "172.31.118.45 - - [15/Jan/2022:04:59:51 +0000] "GET /icon.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 40414 "http://abc/kuma/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0" "24.60.203.85""

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
   # Additionally those headers if websocket/reload is used:
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

   location /svc1/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
   }
   location /svc2/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
   }
   location /svc3/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8083/;
   }
}
```

Don't forget to restart nginx after changing conf!

Comment: This does not work. It gives me a 502

Comment: This means nginx does not get a proper answer from upstream server. Please give logs of nginx and upstream server instead of does not work.. setting up a reverse proxy i not a works/does not work thing..